# Appearance > Menus > Left Sidebar > Add Toggle

Tags: menus

How can i add my own toggle here ? There are toggles for each post type but I would like to add this without creating a new post type. Where should I start looking ?

[image]

Let say I wish to add something like this:[image]

It will work the same as link with URL = # and it will look more clear for some people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You custom box can be added with adding meta box on nav menu page. So -

```
function Register_My_Nav_Menu_Metaboxes(){
    add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, 'nav-menus', 'side' );
}
add_action('load-nav-menu.php', 'Register_My_Nav_Menu_Metaboxes');
```

I hope you know how to add the metabox $id, $title, $callback and utilize it.